# Copying recursively from one directory to another

Tags: shell, recursion

I have three variables:
   `taille` : number of iterations
   `racine` : directory from where to copy
   `rep` : directory where to copy<>br

So the code is supposed to start copying recursively from racine to rep, number of files copied is restricted by taille. I cant seem to make the cp command to work, and i dont know how to make the recursivity to work either. My code is as follows

```
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    taille=0
else
    taille=$1
fi

if [ -z "$2" ]
then
    racine=`pwd`
else
    racine=$2
fi
if [ -z "$3" ]
then
    rep="test2"
else
    rep=$3
fi

    count=0
    for i in `ls $racine`;
    do
        if [ $count -lt $((taille+1)) ]
        then
            echo $i
            `cp $i test2`
        fi  
    count=$((count+1))
    done
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following quick and dirty test script seems to do what you want (more or less).

I'm trying to convey a general approach, not provide a complete solution. What's below will misbehave (look at the `mkdir -p` line) given a relative path (e.g. ../../) for the source directory, so you may have to give that problem a little thought. I hope it conveys the idea clearly enough though.

```
#!/bin/bash

racine="$1"
rep="$2"

declare -i taille=3
declare -i count=0

while read -r -d $'\0'; do
    if [ $count -ge $taille ]; then
        break
    fi

    if [ -d "$REPLY" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$rep/$REPLY";
    else
        cp "$REPLY" "$rep"
    fi

    count=$((count+1))
done < <(find $racine -print0)
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

You don't need the back ticks around the copy command, so just `cp $i test2`.

You increment a variable like this: `` count=`expr $count + 1` ``.

EDIT: The `count=$((count+1))` syntax works if you are using Bash.

Comment: thanks Jeff for the quick response. The modifications you suggested did work, but there are still some weird errors i don't quite understand. Probably it is being caused by the command 'cp'

I am copy pasting the terminal results here

Comment: arj@arj-Inspiron-1545:~/workspace2/SystemeRevision/dec10$ sh ex1.sh 6 /home/arj/Desktop
20140404_183338.jpg
cp: cannot stat ‘20140404_183338.jpg’: No such file or directory
ankita.txt~
cp: cannot stat ‘ankita.txt~’: No such file or directory
bobs
cp: cannot stat ‘bobs’: No such file or directory
carte
cp: cannot stat ‘carte’: No such file or directory
de
cp: cannot stat ‘de’: No such file or directory
sejour~
cp: cannot stat ‘sejour~’: No such file or directory
consoleHelp~

Comment: Those errors are because your `cp` command is saying to copy the file from the current directory, but the files reside in your /home/arj/Desktop directory. You need to prefix the file location ($i) with the directory path.

Comment: BTW, I realized you are probably using Bash, so your original increment code was correct. My example was for the Bourne shell. I'll update my answer.